# operating on pairs of columns in R (or numpy)

Tags: r, numpy, matrix

I have two matrices: A (k rows, m columns), B(k rows, n columns)

I want to operate on all pairs of columns (one from A and one from B), the result should be a matrix C (m rows, n columns) where C[i,j] = f(A[,i],B[,j])
now, if the function f was the sum of the dot product, then the whole thing was just a simple multiplication of matrices (C = t(A) %*% B)
but my f is different (specifically, I count the number equal entries:

```
f = function(x,y) sum(x==y)
```

my question if there is a simple (and fast, because my matrices are big) way to compute the result?

preferably in R, but possibly in python (numpy). I thought about using outer(A,B,"==") but this results in a 4 dimensional array which I havent figured out what exactly to do with it.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `R`, we can `split` them into `list` and apply the function `f` with a nested `lapply/sapply`

```
lapply(asplit(A, 2), function(x) sapply(asplit(B, 2),  function(y) f(x, y)))
```

---

Or using `outer` after converting to `data.frame` because the unit will be column, while for `matrix`, it is a single element (as `matrix` is a `vector` with `dim` attributes)

```
outer(as.data.frame(A), as.data.frame(B), FUN = Vectorize(f))
```

#### data

```
A <- cbind(1:5, 6:10)
B <- cbind(c(1:3, 1:2), c(5:7, 6:7))
```

Comment: The mapply option doesn't seem to work, it doesn't operate on all combinations of columns

Comment: @amit I think `combn` will be  more faster as you may reduce the number of comparisons